# data do not insert to mongo with app.post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, middleware

i use following code that contain get all data get data by id and post data to mongo:

```
const express = require("express");
const app=express();
const _route=require('./router/router.js')
require('dotenv').config();
require('./Database/config.js');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const router=express.Router();
const port_=process.env.PORT|| 8080;
const product=require('./model/model.js');
const res = require("express/lib/response");
const { db } = require("./model/model.js");



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.post('/insert',async(req,res)=>{
    const newProduct=new product({
        _id:req.query._id,
        name:req.query.name,
        description:req.query.description
    });
    try{
        await newProduct.save(); 
           res.json(newProduct);
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    });


    app.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const get= await product.find();
            res.json(get);
        }
        catch(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
    app.get('/:name',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const get=await product.find({name:req.params.name});
            if(get.length===0)
            {
                res.send(`Do not find product with name : ${req.params.id}`);
            }
            else{
            res.json(get);
    }
}
        catch(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
app.listen(port_,'localhost',()=>{ console.log(`App run on port ${port_}`)});
```

when i enter following in address bar for insert data to mongo:
`localhost:3000/insert?_id=36987&name=GLX&description=iranian smart phone`

when use `app.post(...)` data does not post to mongo and  `app.get('/:name',async(req,res)`
run. whenever use `app.use('/insert',...)` instead of `app.post()` data successfully posted to database.
What command should I use? What's my code problem?

Comment: Do you have the same properties in the schema?

Comment: yes, with app.use data insert to database but with app.post() do not insert@Yosi_Leibman

Comment: So I guess the problem is in the body of the request then. what is the body of your request?

Comment: I use following query string in address  bar of browser:localhost:3000/insert?_id=36987&name=GLX&description=iranian smart phone when use app.post(...) get error message can not get/insert @Yosi_Leibman